# Java libGDX one tile smooth movement

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

I have little question how I can do smooth movement in Java LibGDX ?. Something like this:

```
if(walk_right) {
    if(map[cords.x][cords.y] == 1){
        for(float i = 0f; i < 2f; i += 0.001f){ //1 tile 2f;
            cords.x += 0.001f;
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work's player teleporting 1 tile.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work cause you fully update x coordinate between render calls.
You need to smoothly update x coordinate in main game loop.

Simple example:

```
private float velocity = 2f;  //2 units per second
private float walkedDistance = 0f;
private boolean walkRight;

public void walkRight() {
    walkRight = true;
}

public void update(float delta) {
    if(walkRight) {
        float xMovement = delta * velocity;
        walkedDistance += xMovement;
        cords.x += xMovement; 
        if (walkedDistance >= 2) {
            cords.x -= walkedDistance - 2;
            walkRight = false;
            walkedDistance = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I do something than this :

Comment: for(float i = 0f; i < 2f; i += 0.01f){}

Comment: cords.x += 0.001f; and renderPlayer()